# How to make owl carousel using external javascript files without node module

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel

I already made owl carousel from origin template without node_module 'react-owl-carousel'. But now I sometimes see errors such as not adding owl-item class when loading pages.
I imported javascript files like owl-carousel.min.js using node-module 'react-helmet'.

How can I fix that errors completely? Please feel free to answer me about that question.

```js
<Helmet>
    <script src='/js/owl-carousel.min.js' />
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your using ReactJS and importing  owl-carousel.min.js ? as a file am i correct  to avoid node modules and dependency issues , initially i would like to inform you that [OwlCarousel-github](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2)is deprecated, which means its no longer supported by the developer and second of all using the owl-carousel.min.js is just a minified version of the library the creators recommend using [tinyslider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider)

- Also i wanted to mention including a library or a min.js is still a pacakge you would use the difference is you have the file on the project not imported from a cloud delivery network or as an actual file like owl carousel example

  ```
  owlcarousel/
    ├── assets/
    │   ├── owl.carousel.css
    │   ├── owl.carousel.min.css
    │   ├── owl.theme.default.css
    │   ├── owl.theme.default.min.css
    │   ├── owl.theme.green.css
    │   ├── owl.theme.green.min.css
    │   └── owl.video.play.png
    │
    ├── owl.carousel.js
    ├── owl.carousel.min.js
    ├── LICENSE-MIT
    └── README.md
  ```

[Docs - Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html)

```
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Screenshot from github]

Answer (score 3):

You can import javascript and css files in index.html from github owl-carousel repository.